# How to bind an ItemsSource in an AdornedControl to a property of its Adorner?

Tags: wpf, xaml, .net-4.6.1

The below code correctly creates an adorner consisting of multiple WriteBoxes of `InkCanvas` and background lines.

It binds correctly to the properties in the view models.
[Code by Josh Smith](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPFJoshSmith.aspx)

```
<!--XAML that creates the adorned control and the adorner-->      
<ac:AdornedControl IsAdornerVisible="{Binding TranscriptionLayer.IsAdornerVisible}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
    <!--#region  Adorned Element-->
    <!--TranscriptionLayer will have an Adorner (inkcanvas) for handwriting recogntion.
        The RichTextBox is the element being adorned and sets the size of the adornment object (i.e., the inkcanvas writing surface). The RichTextControl holds the actual transcript.-->
    <RichTextBox x:Name="RichTextControl" Panel.ZIndex="{Binding TranscriptionLayer.ZIndex}" Cursor="IBeam" 
                 AllowDrop="True" PreviewDragEnter="RichTextControl_PreviewDragEnter"                           
                 PreviewDragOver="RichTextControl_PreviewDragOver" 
                 PreviewDrop="RichTextControl_PreviewDrop" 
                 Height="{Binding VirtualPage.Height}" 
                 Visibility="{Binding TranscriptionLayer.TranscriptIsVisible}"
                 SpellCheck.IsEnabled="True" 
                 VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
                 AcceptsReturn="True" AcceptsTab="True">
        <!--Remove blank line between paragraphs-->
        <RichTextBox.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Paragraph}">
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
            </Style>
        </RichTextBox.Resources>

        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <!--Update the menu and toolbar when a selection is made in the RichTextBox
                The behavior is bound to the SelectionChanged of the RichTextBox. 
                The normal binding sends the binding source to the dependency property, the target, of the behavior.
                BindsTwoWayByDefault sends the behavior value, the target, back to the Binding source.-->
                    
                     <!--<b:RichTextBehavior AlignLeft ="{Binding TranscriptionLayer.AlignLeft}" /> -->
                        <b:RichTextBehavior 
                            FontHeight="{Binding ElementName=Fontheight, Path=SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={c:NullToDoubleConverter}}"
                            TextFont="{Binding ElementName=Fonttype,     Path=SelectedItem}"
                            TextBold="{Binding ElementName=ToggleBold,   Path=IsChecked}"
                            Italic="{Binding ElementName=ToggleItalic,   Path=IsChecked}"
                            Underline="{Binding ElementName=ToggleUnderline, Path=IsChecked}"
                            Strikethrough="{Binding ElementName=ToggleStrikethrough, Path=IsChecked}"
                            ParagraphTag ="{Binding ElementName=CurrentParagraph, Path=SelectedItem}" 
                            IsFocused ="{Binding TranscriptionLayer.RichTextHasFocus}"
                            MoveText ="{Binding TranscriptionLayer.MoveText}"
                            SelectedText="{Binding TranscriptionLayer.SelectedText}"                              
                            IsImage="{Binding TranscriptionLayer.IsImage}"
                            DeleteImage="{Binding TranscriptionLayer.DeleteImage}"
                        />
                    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>

                </RichTextBox>

                <!--#endregion-->
                <ac:AdornedControl.AdornerContent>
                    <!--#region  The Adorner-->
                    <!-- This is the framework element as the adorner content. It is always on top of the adorned element. There adorned elements
                         is the RichTextConttrol.
                         The ItemsControl will expand to the width of the parent adorner which takes its size from the adorned element-the
                         RichTextConttrol. The ItemsControl inherits from  System.Windows.FrameworkElement. 
                    -->
                    
                        <ItemsControl x:Name="WritingLayerControl" ItemsSource="{Binding TranscriptionLayer.WritingBoxes}" >
                            <!--
                            If the  <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel> is not used, the ItemsControl will default to a vertical StackPanel.
                        -->

                            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                <!--
                            DataTemplate and DataType point to a class, not a namespace!
                        -->
                                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:WritingBoxViewModel}" >
                                    <Grid>
                                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <!-- 0 to be used for recogntion results-->
                                            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                                            <!-- 1 to be used for Ink -->
                                            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding RecognitionResults}" Background="#100000FF" 
                                               Height="{Binding RecognitionResultsHeight}"/>

                                        <!--     
                                Binding Mode must be set to TwoWay on TheSelectedStrokes because by default binding works one way, 
                                i.e. loading changes from the view model, but not updating the viewmodel back. So either use:
                                TheSelectedStrokes="{Binding SelectedStrokes, Mode=TwoWay}" or set it with
                                FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault in TheSelectedStrokes dependency definition.
                            
                                Background is of type Brush, so must use ImageBrush, DrawingBrush, VisualBrush.
                                -->

                                        <InkCanvas x:Name="InkCanvas" Grid.Row="1" 
                                   Height="{Binding WritingBoxHeight}" Strokes="{Binding Strokes}"  
                                   EditingMode="{Binding EditingMode}"
                                   DefaultDrawingAttributes="{Binding DefaultDrawingAttributes}" >

                                            <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                                                <b:InkCanvasBehavior DeletedStrokes="{Binding DrawingLayer.DeleteStrokes}" />
                                            </i:Interaction.Behaviors>

                                            <InkCanvas.Background>
                                                <!--
                                    Note: Making the DrawingBrush a StaticResource makes the XAML much more efficient as only one object
                                        is created. It also is only created on the first pass and no update from the Bindings will happen so
                                        the lines will not change even when the TypeSize is changed.
                                   
                                    Viewport (type Rect) gives the position, width, and height of the base tile
                                    -->
                                                <DrawingBrush Stretch="Uniform" TileMode="Tile" Viewport="{Binding ViewPortBaseTile}" ViewportUnits="Absolute" >
                                                    <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                                                        <GeometryDrawing>
                                                            <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                                                                
                                      <GeometryGroup>
                                                                    <!--
                                                        X is horizontal displacement from origin.
                                                            Y is veritcal displacyement from origin.
                                                            Origin O(0,0) is top-left of InkCanvas.
                                                        -->
                                            <!-- Vertical Line                        
                                            <LineGeometry StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="{Binding TileBottom}"/>-->
                                            <!-- Midline. Horizontal Line -->                                
                                            <LineGeometry StartPoint="{Binding MidLineStartPoint}" EndPoint="{Binding MidLineEndPoint}"/>

                                            <!-- BaseLine. Horizontal Line-->                               
                                            <LineGeometry StartPoint="{Binding BaseLineStartPoint}" EndPoint="{Binding BaseLineEndPoint}"/>  
                                        </GeometryGroup>  
                  
                                        </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>               
                                            <GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                                                <Pen Thickness="1" Brush="Tomato"/>                                                       
                                            </GeometryDrawing.Pen>                                                        
                                        </GeometryDrawing>                                  
                                    </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                                </DrawingBrush>
                            </InkCanvas.Background>
                        </InkCanvas>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>         
        <!--#endregion-->
    </ac:AdornedControl.AdornerContent>
</ac:AdornedControl>
```

Now, I would like to change:

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="WritingLayerControl" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding TranscriptionLayer.WritingBoxes}">
```

So that the `WritingBoxes` property is located in the `Adorner` class itself -- not in the ViewModel. In the ViewModel it is defined as:

```
private ObservableCollection<WritingBoxViewModel> _writingBoxes;
     
public ObservableCollection<WritingBoxViewModel> WritingBoxes
{
    get { return _writingBoxes; }
    set 
    { 
        if (_writingBoxes == value) 
            return; 

        _writingBoxes = value; 
        RaisePropertyChanged(); 
    }
}
```

Keeping in mind, the `Adorner` may or may not be visible at any given time.

How can I bind the `ItemsSource` in the `AdornedControl` to a property in the Adorner?

Comment: Did you try `RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}`? You can also try to edit `Adorner`'s template and use `TemplateBinding`.

Comment: @AndreyAlonzov Yes. I did try all forms of RelativeSource including FindAncestor without luck. I do not know, at this time, what changes would have to be made to the Template...Any Ideas?  Thanks.